# When I install CA certificate to local computer (TR), same key get installed in current user as well

Tags: ssl, iis, web-deployment, x509certificate2, certificate-authority

Hi I'm setting up my web site with certificate authentication. When I installed the client authentication Certificate on the server to Local Computer\Trusted Root, it get installed to Current User\Trusted Root as well. So I get 403 error.

If I delete the certificate in current user, it deletes the key in local computer as well.

Anyone has any idea?

Thank you

Comment: How do you install? Are you using Microsoft Management Console  (MMC)?

Comment: yes that's correct. I also tried double clicking the .cer files

Comment: Whats the end result you want? If the certificate is installed you won't get 403.

Comment: yes, certificate is installed but I get the error 403. coz certificate is present in both local and current machine root. I guess

Comment: you need to install client/server certificates to Personal store, not to Trusted Root CAs.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple issues in your case.

1. The behaviour you describe is by design. When you install the certificate to `Local Machine` store (except `Personal` container) are automatically propagated to all users on the system. When you delete the certificate with local administrator permissions, it is deleted from `Local Machine` too.
2. only root CA certificates should be installed in the `Local Machine\Trusted Root CAs` store. No personal certificates shall be installed there. These certificates are plain certificate (`.cer`) and used only to establish a trust to a third-party CA.
3. client authentication certificates MUST include private key. As per your comments, you are attempting to install `.cer` file which is plain public certificate without private key. There should be something with either, `.pfx` or `.p12` file extension. These are PFX certificates with private keys.

you need to sort things out to determine what certificate types you have (end-entity or CA) and install them accordingly: CA certificates to `Local Machine\Trusted Root CAs`, end-entity (client authentication) to `Current User\Personal` (of each respective user).

Comment: Thanks for your information. Yes I'm trying to install root CA certificate on the IIS server. This is the common company certificate as a .cer file. when I tried to install this to Local Machine\Trusted Root, it goes to Current User\Personal as well. Then I get 403 error